# Pop Up notifications on a daily/weekly/monthly basis depending on the selected date

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, notifications

Here the user is able to pick a date(goal date) using datepicker. The date gets saved in the database. Then the notification pops up on the screen only if the due date is within 2 days. I wanted to figure out how to show the notification on a daily / weekly / monthly basis depending on the date selected. I checked different sites but didnt get a proper solution. Please help!

MainActivity

```
swipelist.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(final int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            // ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
            final MyImage image = (MyImage) swipelist.getItemAtPosition((int) position);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // open

                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    View DateView = li.inflate(R.layout.calendar_cam, null);
                    build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    build.setTitle("Reminder");
                    build.setMessage("Pick a date");
                    build.setView(DateView);
                    newDate = (Button) DateView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCalCam); //Button which opens the calender
                    newDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                        }
                    });

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                    build.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put(DBhelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, dateString);
                            Log.d("Updating Date: ", ".....");
                            String whereClause =
                                    DBhelper.COLUMN_TITLE + "=? AND " + DBhelper.COLUMN_DATETIME + "=?";
                            String[] whereArgs = new String[]{image.getTitle(), String.valueOf(image.getDatetimeLong())};
                            database.update(DBhelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, whereClause, whereArgs);
                            Log.d("Updating Date: ", ".....");
                            image.setDescription(dateString);
                            swipelist.invalidateViews();

                            //Scheduling Notifications
                            int curYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR), curMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, curDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            int goalYear = Integer.parseInt(yearG), goalMonth = Integer.parseInt(monthG), goalDay = Integer.parseInt(dayG);
                            int calYear = 0, calMonth = 0, calDay = 0, calDayGoal = 0;

                            //Get current date
                            String curDate = String.valueOf(curDay) + "/" + String.valueOf(curMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(curYear);

                            //Get goal date
                            String goalDate = String.valueOf(goalDay) + "/" + String.valueOf(goalMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(goalYear);
                            int count = -1;

                            //Fetches the date and Time from system, hence not used
                            if (curYear < goalYear || (goalYear == curYear && goalMonth > curMonth) || (goalYear == curYear && goalMonth == curMonth && goalDay > curDay)) {
                                count = 0;
                                int i;
                                for (i = curYear; i < goalYear; i++) {
                                    if (i % 4 == 0) {
                                        count += 366;//Leap year
                                    } else {
                                        count += 365;// Non leap year
                                    }
                                }
                                //calculating the no of days left from current date to goal date
                                count -= calMonthDay(curMonth, curYear);
                                count -= curDay;
                                count += calMonthDay(goalMonth, goalYear);
                                count += goalDay;
                                if (count < 0) {
                                    count *= -1;
                                }


                                if (count != 1) {
                                    daysLeftGoal.add(String.valueOf(count) + " days left");
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Days Left: "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else
                                    daysLeftGoal.add(String.valueOf(count) + " day left");
                            } else {// current year exceeds goal year
                                daysLeftGoal.add("Times up");
                            }
                            mContext=getApplicationContext();
                            // check if goal date is less than or equals 2 days
                            if (count <= 2 && count >= 0) {
                                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                //resultIntent.putExtra("ID", mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelperGoal.KEY_ID)));
                                resultIntent.putExtra("update", true);
                                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  //TaskStackBuilder requires API 16 [4.1] min
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
                                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
                                    //stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                                    resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 } else {
                                    resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                    //deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                }
 gBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                        .setContentTitle("My Goals")
                                        .setContentText("Reminder Set: " + image.getDescription())
                                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "View", resultPendingIntent);
                                        //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_discard, "Delete", deletePendingIntent);
                                gBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                                //gBuilder.setContentIntent(deletePendingIntent);
                                gBuilder.setPriority(2);// [-2,2]->[PRIORITY_MIN,PRIORITY_MAX]

                                //for the sound and float notification
                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);//set the alarm time
                                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 57);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                                gBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000}).setLights(Color.WHITE, 0, 1);
                                //gBuilder.setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis()).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE).setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)).setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }).setLights(Color.WHITE, 0, 1);

                                // opens the resultPendingIntent
                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                // open the activity every 24 hours
                                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, resultPendingIntent);

                                gBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                                //int mNotificationId = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelperGoal.KEY_ID));
                                //keyIndex = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelperGoal.KEY_ID));
                                int mNotificationId=position;

                                // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
                                myGoalNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                // Builds the notification and issues it.
                                myGoalNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId,  gBuilder.build());
   }
                        }
                    });
                    alert=build.create();
                    alert.show();
                    break;
```

// calculates days from months

```
int calMonthDay(int m,int y){//calMonthDay(month,year)
    int x=0,c;
    for(c = 1; c < m; c++) {// Jan to less than the month 'm' as 'm' we are not taking the the whole days of that month
        if(c == 2) {//if Feb
            if(y%4 == 0)//checks if year is leap or not
                x += 29;
            else
                x += 28;
        }
        else
            x += mon.get(c-1);
    }
    return(x);
}
```

//calculates no. of months from current month & year to goal month & year

```
int calDateMonth(int mC,int yC,int mG,int yG){//(current-month, current-year, goal-month, goal-year)
    int x = 0,i,countM=0;
    if(yC<=yG){
        for(i = yC; i < yG; i++)
            countM += 12;
    }

    countM -= mC;
    countM += mG;
    return (countM);
}
```

//calculates no. of weeks from current month & year to goal month & year

```
int calDateWeek(int mC,int yC,int mG,int yG){
    int x = 0,i,countW=0;
    if(yC<=yG){
        for(i = yC; i < yG; i++)
            countW+=52;
    }

    countW -= mC;
    countW += mG;
    countW *= 4;
    return (countW);
}
```

DatePicker

```
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener reservationDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        int curYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR), curMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, curDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        //Picks the selected date, month & year & displays on button
        if((year>curYear)||(year==curYear && month+1>curMonth)||(year==curYear && month+1==curMonth && day>curDay)) {
            dayG = Integer.toString(day);
            monthG = Integer.toString(month + 1);
            yearG = Integer.toString(year);
            Log.d("Setting Date: ", ".....");
            dateString=String.valueOf(dayG)+"-"+String.valueOf(monthG)+"-"+String.valueOf(yearG);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your reminder is set to "  + day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please choose date after " + curDay + "-" + curMonth + "-" + curYear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So, is this not working? Are there any errors in particular that you're seeing? Since it sounds like it's not doing what you want, what *is it* doing?

Comment: @jeffdill2 it shows the notification only if I pick a date 1 or 2 days from the current date. So if I pick a date after 2 days, it doesnt show the notification.

Comment: @jeffdill2 example: If I set the date on 1 st June 2016, then I want to show the notifcation as a reminder to the user on a weekly/monthly basis indicating certain number of days left till the goal date. and when the due date arrives, it should show as "time up!"